# how to fix rows getting "None" when using .apply function in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, series

Im working on a large dataset of 7GB were i need to use BERT AI algorithm for text classification,
i used a random dataset i found on kaggle as an alternative example to minimise the process time and to apply a function i created (for future use on the original dataset) to clean the text by removing punctuations and lemmatize words etc,.So when i chose the column "Message to examine to clean all the texts there by using the .apply from pandas library, it works fine but when i add the result i get to a new dataframe or to the same dataframe, all rows turns into empty rows with no value. anyone knows how can i fix this issue?

[explanation of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eae0p.png)

i tried the lambda function inside apply

```
newtext['message to examine'] = newtext['message to examine'].apply(lambda x : clean_text(x))
```

i tried copying the dataframe and store it to a new one

```
newdataframe = pd.DataFrame(df['message to examine'].apply(cleantext)).copy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this happens when one forgets to add a return statement to their apply function, which in this case is your clean_text.

As a side-note, you can simply do .apply(clean_text) without the lambda function.

Comment: The function works fine when i execute it, it shows the result in a series apart, but when i add the result to the column it fills the column inside the dataframe with none . Thats the problem

Comment: Any way to share some version of the function?

Comment: well, the return statement was commented, thank you for your help, it worked now